# Can I use a Yongnuo YN-600EX-RT flash on a Sony Alpha DSLT?

Tags: canon, flash, sony, yongnuo

I'm planning to change my kit and move to Sony SLT system (I have special, personal reasons).

I currently own the above mentioned flash. I would like to know how I possibly could use it on a Sony SLT camera, like the Alpha 58 or Alpha 77 II for example. Can I even use it? If yes, what are the limitations? For example does the E-TTL feature work in some way?

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the YN-600EX-RT on the Sony multi-interface hotshoe, since both the flash and hotshoe are ISO-compliant, but on the camera hotshoe it can only be used in M mode, and will not perform anything but proper sync. You'll have to dial in the power level, it won't do TTL, HSS, or any of the extra stuff you're used to it doing on a Canon dSLR.  None of the pins on the flash's foot, other than the sync pin, will connect to anything on the Sony hotshoe (the contacts are all on the side, not on the bottom plate).

However.

If you are using it off-camera and you also have the YN-E3-RT (the Canon ST-E3-RT cannot do this, btw--it has to be the Yongnuo unit), you can (theoretically) still have remote manual power level and zoom control from the Sony SLT.  You may have to hit the TEST button to send the settings to the flash before each shot, but the legacy/mirrorless custom function should allow for this use.

See: [A flash havoc article on using the YN-E3-RT on non-Canon cameras](http://flashhavoc.com/yn-e3-rt-adds-remote-manual-for-non-canon-cameras/), and [Can I get HSS with off-camera Canon 430EX II speedlites, radio triggers, and a Sony A7?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61291/can-i-get-hss-with-off-camera-canon-430ex-ii-speedlites-radio-triggers-and-a-s)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the A-series, but  I have the E-mount Sony A7 and Sony A6000 and they both work manually with my yongnuo flashes, however, as far as I know you will not have E-TTL or TTL unless you buy the Sony specific flashes.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer, I've expected something like this.