# Will Yongnuo YN685 (Nikon) on-camera trigger with YN622C off-camera?

Tags: nikon, flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

I accidentally ordered a [Yongnuo YN-685](https://www.photo-store.net/photography/yongnuo-flashes/yongnuo-yn685/) for Nikon and a [YN-622N](https://www.photo-store.net/photography/yongnuo-flash-triggers/yongnuo-yn622n-ii/) for my Canon camera.

Are these Yongnuo YN-685-Nikon compatible with YN-622C? Or I should change all to Canon?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Possibly see: [Can I trigger Yongnuo YN-622N and YN-622C together at the same time?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77055) and [Are Yongnuo flashes interchangeable between dslr's or are they brand specific?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62373) Is there a reason you can't just return the wrong gear and get the right ones instead?

Comment: The YN685 (Nikon) is a flash, not a trigger. Do you mean you accidentally ordered the Canon version of the YN685?

Comment: Yeah, you may be right about that. But my comment was an observation regarding the title, which is as originally asked. It seems to label the YN685 (Nikon) as a trigger.

Comment: yes my camera is canon i  accidentally orderd a  Yongnuo YN-685 nikon and a YN-622N so what im asking is if i brought only YN-622C Canon one is it flash YN-685 nikon

Comment: Are you sure that [Can I trigger Yongnuo YN-622N and YN-622C together at the same time?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77055) doesn't answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these Yongnuo YN-685-Nikon compatible with YN-622C?

No.

> Or I should change all to Canon?

Yes.

See: [Can I trigger Yongnuo YN-622N and YN-622C together at the same time?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77055)